# Publish infopath form from document library to custom list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-list

I have created the form using InfoPath and published as form in document library.

Now I want to republish the same form in a SharePoint custom list (the ist is already created), I just want to move the form from the document library to the custom list.

Comment: An InfoPath form can't be published as a list. By definition, the form is basically an XML file. If you just want the field values, there may be some way to get those.

Comment: Are you need to create InfoPath form for a custom list ?

Answer (score 0):

Save your InfoPath form to a different location using save as.

Then publish the form to the new destination by doing:

Go to the File Tab
Select Publish from the toolbar on the left
Select Sharepoint Server
Specify details of the destination: Server address, list name, etc
The form will then be available on the specified destination

Reference:

Move [InfopathForm](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-a-published-form-template-to-a-new-SharePoint-library-2a2aac61-3180-40fc-b306-61e8d7829bf8)

Comment: This will only work for moving the form to a document library, not to a list

Comment: Now I want to publish the form in survey. How to do it